# How can I solve Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/)

Tags: apt, dpkg

I am really New to UBUNTU 14.04 and whenever I try to update or install anything I get this error:

```
sudo apt-get update [sudo] password for trojanfm: 
E: Could not ge lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily
unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/ 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) 
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: Probably you run 2 instances of program or you have synaptic or  some another package manager.

Comment: Wait for few minutes because apt-get update may have been running in background. This happens when you have just started the ubuntu. Try to run `apt-get update`, DO NOT DELETE ANYTHING FIRST.

Comment: I found this question instead of duplicate, and also this one helped me and not the linked duplicate one.

Comment: I don't think much of any of the answers here. It might be better to find out which process has the lock and kill that process. See this for more info: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1858466

Answer (score 65):

search for processes. Since Ubuntu 16.04, "apt" is used instead of "apt-get"

`ps -A | grep apt-get`

or

`ps -aux | grep 'apt-get'`

or

`ps -A | grep apt`

then see if there any process running as apt-get/apt

kill that process it by using:

```
sudo kill -9 <process-id>
```

for example if process id is 2345

```
sudo kill -9 2345
```

then run the sudo apt-get update

Edit: If you are sure that you have no instances of dpkg or apt running and you still get the message, you can just delete the file:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

A lock file is just a file with zero size that indicates locking of a resource.

**Update:**

As of Ubuntu 16.04 release, **apt-get** was replaced with **apt**.  The running process can be located with:

```
ps -A | grep apt
```

Comment: I am running no other dpkg program :\

Comment: ubuntu automatically check for updates once the system boot up, it is not you, it is the system.

Comment: best way is wait for few minutes while it search for update then run your update command or kill apt-get process, and run manually. once the system boots, it automatically runs sudo apt-get update to search for latest update. :)

Comment: it should work :)

Comment: If the state was reached after you manually terminated an apt-get installation, then use: sudo dpkg --configure -a

Comment: No such process running.

Comment: In kali 2016.2, i need to do `sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock` and `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock` to make it works (both paths can get from the error message).